# Angularjs append message to div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular and socket.io to create a chat for my application, and sending/receiving messages works just fine, but my question is, how do I append new message to the current chat? I feel that saving each message in an `array` and then using `ng-repeat` on all the `array` is the wrong way to go.

What can I do in Angular to append items to the div?

```
var app = angular.module('ChatModule', []);
var socket = io("ws://localhost:3030");

app.controller('TextChat', function($scope){

    socket.on('Chat', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });

    $scope.$send = function(){
        socket.emit('Chat', $scope.ChatMessage);
        $scope.ChatMessage = "";
    };
});
```

So, in the `socket.on` event, what can I do to append the message to this div?

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-model="Messages"></div>
```

Comment: I don't necessarily think storing in an array and using `ng-repeat` is the *wrong* way to go.  It would not be the "angular-way" to do DOM manipulations on that div yourself or to just append to some string

Comment: why you think that using `ng-repeat` here is wrong way? if you see a bit deeper you can see that `ng-repeat` not render all array on receive any message, but just add to dom just new messages

Comment: I just feel that the array would get too big and really start to slow down rebuilding or other aspects of the page

Comment: You can trim it as it comes in, assuming it's a chat log you'll only show upto x anyways?

Comment: you can consider jqlite option in angular

Comment: @GopinathShiva I would not recommend that , especially consider he's using sockets, bind to something in a scope and let angular work it's magic.

Comment: Depends on how big the array will be, If it's to big and become I performance problem I would use a directive that appends the message to the DOM otherwise I would use array with ng-repeat with track by.

Comment: I think using array simply is the angular-way. When you actually face the the performance problem, you can use some other solution like pager or something.